# how can i sort data with a array element in mongodb without using unwind

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

this is my sample data in this I have a userId and a array "watchHistory", "watchHistory" array contains the list of videos that is watched by the user :

```
    {
        "_id": "62821344445c30b35b441f11",
        "userId": 579,
        "__v": 0,
        "watchHistory": [
            {
                "seenTime": "2022-05-23T08:29:19.781Z",
                "videoId": 789456,
                "uploadTime": "2022-03-29T12:33:35.312Z",
                "description": "Biography of Indira Gandhi",
                "speaker": "andrews",
                "title": "Indira Gandhi",
                "_id": "628b45df775e3973f3a670ec"
            },
            {
                "seenTime": "2022-05-23T08:29:39.867Z",
                "videoId": 789455,
                "uploadTime": "2022-03-31T07:37:39.712Z",
                "description": "What are some healthy food habits to stay healthy",
                "speaker": "morris",
                "title": "Healthy Food Habits",
                "_id": "628b45f3775e3973f3a670"
            },
            
        ]
    }
```

I need to match the userId and after that i need to sort it with "watchHistory.seenTime", seenTime field indicates when the user saw the video. so i need to sort like the last watched video should come first in the list.
I don't have permission to use unwind so can any one help me from this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB version 5.2 and above, you can use `$sortArray` operator in an aggregation pipeline. Your pipeline should look something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {"$match": 
      { _id: '62821344445c30b35b441f11' }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        _id: 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "__v": 1,
        "watchHistory": {
          "$sortArray": { input: "$watchHistory", sortBy: { seenTime: -1 }}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Please modify the filter for "$match" stage, according to the key and value you need to filter on. Here's the link to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/).

Without using `unwind`, it's not possible to do it via an aggregation pipeline, but you can use `update` method and `$push` operator, as a workaround like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "62821344445c30b35b441f11"
},
{
  $push: {
    watchHistory: {
      "$each": [],
      "$sort": {
        seenTime: -1
      },
    }
  }
})
```

Please see the working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/68geaTtlpCj)

Comment: hi @Charchit Kapoor, thank you for your answer. but my mongodb version is 3.6.8 so I am unable to use the sort array operation and it returning a error. I am unable to update the mongodb also. Is there any other solution to solve this.